# Can't change Low Threshold to 0 in set options

Tags: transactions, stellar-laboratory, multi-sig, authorization, set-options

I did set `low` threshold on my issuer account to `5`, but I didn't add any additional signer.

Now I want revert low threshold to `0` but I receive `tx_bad_auth` error.

Is there any way to set low threshold to `0` again?

Issuer account public key: 
`GBYZDFZTJNVS3IKWWBJUS5W3LFAHGNITGQOQ5KTGZXIQ3UGJS7SIQCHU`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you'll need one more Stellar account for this. Account QCHU (original account) will be unable to pay tx fees until you change the low threshold back to 0.

1. Create one more Stellar account (let's call it "auxiliary" account) with minimum balance 1.1 XLM.
2. Using [Stellar Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#txbuilder?params=eyJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7ImZlZSI6IjEwMCJ9fQ%3D%3D&network=public) prepare a transaction

   - Use **auxiliary** account public key as a **transaction source** account.
   - Add single `SET_OPTIONS` operation, copy-paste your **original** account address to the **operation source** field.
   - Set thresholds back to 0 / 0 / 0.
3. Make sure that you pressed the *"Fetch next sequence number for account starting with..."* button to fetch correct sequence number for the **auxiliary** account.
4. Sign the transaction with **both original and auxiliary secret keys**. Your transaction should have exactly two signatures.
5. Submit the transaction to the network.
6. That's it. Your original account thresholds are restored. You can now merge the auxiliary account back to the original account to reclaim 1 XLM base reserve.